# Free plugin for construct filterable tables

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm using Wordpress + Mysql for intranet website. Is there some free plugins for Wordpress or in Jquery to create Tables from MySQL query with filters, search, sorting and function to export to Excel, PDF.

I'm now using FooTable, but there not possible to filter and export to Excel, PDF.

Comment: check out https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-jquery-datatable/

Comment: i use jquery DataTables plugin this plugin for puproses you've mentioned. https://datatables.net/

Comment: but there for mysql data tables need to use AJAX? or also may from simple php code?